# Google plus language programming using people.list

Tags: c#, list, oauth, geometry

as a new researcher I am trying to get information about relations among people on G+. I want to get other's circle list for some research purpose. It seems that the G+ API offers a web version to use people.list with a OAuth2 token. My question is, does people.list support programming language such as c#, java? I tried with c# but it seems to be blocked by the server.

Is there is a way to apply people.list in c#,java etc? If yes, are there some samples? Or someone provide some open codes to fullfill similar functions?

thanks very much.

the following is my related c# code:

```
var provider = new NativeApplicationClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description)
                {
                    ClientIdentifier = credentials.ClientId,
                    ClientSecret = credentials.ClientSecret
                };
            var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<NativeApplicationClient>(provider, GetAuthorization);


        var servicelist = new PlusService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            Authenticator = auth
        });

        string userId = "********************";
        PeopleResource.ListRequest circle = servicelist.People.List(userId, new PeopleResource.Collection());
        circle.MaxResults = 5;
        PeopleFeed danielfeed = circle.Fetch();
```

---

```
    private static IAuthorizationState GetAuthorization(NativeApplicationClient arg)
    {
        IAuthorizationState state = new AuthorizationState(new[] { TasksService.Scopes.Tasks.GetStringValue() });
        state.Callback = new Uri(NativeApplicationClient.OutOfBandCallbackUrl);
        Uri authUri = arg.RequestUserAuthorization(state);

        Process.Start(authUri.ToString());
        Console.Write("  Authorization Code: ");
        string authCode = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine();

        return arg.ProcessUserAuthorization(authCode, state);
    }
}
```

The program goes wrong at "PeopleFeed danielfeed = circle.Fetch();" I think I have already passed the OAuth token to the people.list function by variable "auth". Can you give me some advices?

Comment: Google doesn't block languages, it blocks invalid requests. If you show some code, maybe we could find what's wrong? Also, I'm not familiar with "people.list", could you elaborate?

Comment: yes, the following is my related c# code:

Answer (score 0):

Google's [People:list API's documentation is here](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people/list). The entire API is [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#RESTful_web_services), and does not block any language.

You can use C#, and just need to learn how to consume a REST API in C#. The C# class you will want to use is the HttpClient class. It is very well documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) and there are plenty of tutorials online, as well as here on SO.